# Use keyboard shortcuts to access bookmark function in texmaker

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

is it at all possible to use keyboard shortcuts to activate the bookmark function of texmaker? So that one could jump quickly between different parts of the ducument?

e.g. go to bookmark 1: `ctrl+shift+1`; go to bookmark 2: `ctrl+shift+2`

I could not find this functionality in the shortcuts section of the options of texmaker.

I would be fully willing to edit some config file, if I only knew how this command would be called.

This would truly speed up my workflow.

Comment: The manual says "click the buttons", so I don't think there's a way from within texmaker. You can use an external automation software like Autohotkey (win) or Autokey (linux) to assign keyboard shortcuts  to scripts that will do the mouse moves for you but that means you can't move/resize the editor window. In linux you can do that with a bash script also. But TeXstudio, a fork of TeXmaker, has this functionality built-in (10 bookmarks assigned to Ctrl+1, .., 0 which can be reassigned, of course). My advice is to switch to TeXstudio. There are Qs on this site about one vs the other if needed.

Comment: I tried texstudio once, and was a bit annoyed by the overly exhaustive code completion which always knew better than me, what I wanted, when I wanted to type something entirely differen ;-), but maybe it's time to give it another go. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You can disable the autocompletion in TeXstudio fom menu > Options > Configure > Completion > Automatically start completer .... checkbox.